# Find points on a line with specific distance to another point

Tags: geometry, vectors

What is the best way to find the distances of points $X_1$ and $X_2$ from point $A$, using their distance $R$ from point $B$, the positions of points $A$ and $B$, and a normalized vector $V$ defining a line going through point $A$? Everything is happening in 2D. Note, that I'm interested only in their distance from the point $A$ and so far the best solution is to calculate their positions first. I feel there must be a simpler solution.

[image]

Comment: You need to know either the slope, or the angle of the line relative to the line $\overline{AB}$.

Comment: @Don Thousand you can calculate the angle as the angle between vectors V and B-A

Comment: You know the line through $A$ is of the form $y = mx + c$. You also know the point $B$. So you know the equation of the circle is given as $(x-B_1)^2 + (y-B_2)^2 = R^2$. Plug in the value of $y$ as $mx + c$ to obtain the points of intersection of the circle and the line. You will get a quadratic in $x$, the roots of which will give you the $x$-coordinates of $X_1$ and $X_2$. You can get the $y$ coordinates by $y = mx + c$ and compute the distances. I am sure there would be an easier way if you are just interested in the distance, but I guess this would atleast help you get to the solution.

Comment: I edited the question to better represent what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, because I needed only the closest point anyway, I ended up using this equation:

$$-\frac{d \cdot v + \sqrt{\vphantom{\bigl(}r^2  \lVert d\rVert^2 - \lVert d \times v\rVert}}{\lVert d\rVert^2}$$

$v$ is unit vector with the direction of the line

$d$ is the vector $A-B$

$r$ is the distance from $B$

Answer (score 1):

Let $H$ be the midpoint of $[X_1 X_2]$. Compute the distance $BH$ : it is the distance between point $B$ and line $(X_1X_2)$.

Now, use Pythagoras theorem to compute the distances $AH$, $HX_1$ and $HX_2$.

You now have $AX_1 = AH - HX_1$ and $AX_2 = AH + HX_1$.

Answer (score 0):

With $p = (x,y)$ the solution is at the intersection of two locus. A line $L$ and a circle $C$

$$
\cases{
L\to p = A + \lambda \vec v\\
C\to ||p-B|| = r
}
$$

so

$$
||A+\lambda\vec v-B||^2=r^2
$$

or

$$
||A-B||^2-2\lambda (A-B)\cdot \vec v + \lambda^2||\vec v||^2 = r^2
$$

now solving for $\lambda$ we have one two or no outcomes at all. One in case of tangency, two in case of strict intersection or none in case of no intersection. Supposing we have strict intersection, then having two outcomes $\lambda^*_1,\lambda^*_2$ we have

$$
X_1 = A+\lambda^*_1\vec v\\
X_2 = A+\lambda^*_2\vec v\\
$$

We can have directly those distances if previously the vector $\vec v$ was normalized.